# Why don't these two dates from jQuery UI's datepicker compare correctly in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-comparison

I have been trying to work with comparing dates and times using jQuery UI's datepicker and the timepicker add-on (an add-on I have just discovered and am very happy with).

So, here's what I have:

**First, the expected values from the `$("#dateOfAb").val()` and the `$("#dateOfAb2").val()` both use the datetimepicker with the following formatting:**

**Time:**

*$("#dateOfAb, #dateOfAb2").datetimepicker({ timeFormat: "hh:mm tt", stepMinute: 15 });*

**AND, although not explicitly set (It seems to be the default date formatting for said plug-in):**

*dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"*

**(example output: 08/16/2013 12:00 am)**

So, I need to compare these dates and while I have had success comparing dates in the past, I am having trouble comparing times for equal dates (which is the ultimate goal), but what is holding me up right now is the fact that I can't get these two `parseDate` values (on substrings from the full date/time) to show that they are equal when the dates are the same.

Okay, that last paragraph may be a little confusing so, here's the code:

```
$("#dateOfAb2").change(function () {
    console.log("FIRST SET: " + $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#dateOfAb").val().substring(0, 9)))
    console.log("FIRST SET: " + $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#dateOfAb2").val().substring(0, 9)))

    if ($.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#dateOfAb").val().substring(0, 9)) == $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#dateOfAb2").val().substring(0, 9))) {
        alert("The dates are tied.");
        console.log("SECOND SET: " + $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#dateOfAb").val().substring(0, 9)))
        console.log("SECOND SET: " + $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#dateOfAb2").val().substring(0, 9)))
    }
});
```

The problem is that even when I know the values are exactly the same (proven with `console.log()` [image below]) they don't seem to compare as I would expect in my `if` branch.

Image of console after running:

[image]

You can see that I have substringed out just the date part of the value and the values are the same, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why the "SECOND SET:" of `console.log()` commands won't execute.

Comment: Which date-picker plugin are you using?

Comment: @losnir I just wanted to extend a thanks for your help on this, as well, Sir.

Comment: I hardly did anything, but thanks! :-)

Comment: @losnir Well, you would have if Pointy had been a little slower :-) Thanks to you both for your time and help.

Comment: @losnir Oh, and actually, you did help me in reminding me that using functions like `getTime()` was just another way of gathering the appropriate property (or computations on properties) from the object (like `toString()`), so thanks for that, too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parse routine returns Date objects, so your comparison is between two separate object instances. They'll *never* be `==` to each other.

Try:

```
if ($.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#dateOfAb").val().substring(0, 9)).getTime() == $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#dateOfAb2").val().substring(0, 9)).getTime()) {
```

By comparing the results of calling `.getTime()`, you're comparing two numbers for equality, which will do what you want.

Comment: I was just about to post that. Oh well. +1 :)

Comment: @VoidKing By the way, you can use `.toString()` instead, if you wish to compare the two strings (as shown in your screenshot).

Comment: @losnir yes, the strings would be fine too, though (unimportantly) it's probably a little faster to compare the numbers.

Comment: @Pointy Nice! Thanks guys (you too, losnir). A quick check of this has seemed to work. You know, I saw this method during some of my searching, but I didn't think it would be valid since, in my example, I was comparing just the dates and not the times, lol. I guess I got hung up with the technical syntax difference between the words "time" and "date" that I forgot a separate `getTime()` method would consider any parse-able datepart as time.

Comment: @Pointy Also, in retrospect, I can tell I was expecting `parseDate()` to do with the data what `getTime()` does, but that's really an error on my part because I should have expected `parseDate()` to parse the info into an object, as it does.